# HDFS access from remote host through Java API, user authentication

Tags: java, security, authentication, hadoop, hdfs

I need to use HDFS cluster from remote desktop through Java API. Everything works OK until it comes to write access. If I'm trying to create any file I receive access permission exception. Path looks good but exception indicates my remote desktop user name which is of course is not what I need to access needed HDFS directory.

The question is:
- Is there any way to represent different user name using 'simple' authentication in Java API?
- Could you please point some good explanation of authentication / authorization schemes in hadoop / HDFS preferable with Java API examples?

Yes, I already know 'whoami' could be overloaded in this case using shell alias but I prefer to avoid solutions like this. Also specifics here is I dislike usage of some tricks like pipes through SSH and scripts. I'd like to perform everything using just Java API.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After some studying I came to the following solution:

- I don't actually need the full Kerberos solution, it is enough currently that clients can run HDFS requests from any user. Environment itself is considered secure.
- This gives me solution based on hadoop UserGroupInformation class. In future I can extend it to support Kerberos.

Sample code probably useful for people both for 'fake authentication' and remote HDFS access:

```
package org.myorg;

import java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;

public class HdfsTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            UserGroupInformation ugi
                = UserGroupInformation.createRemoteUser("hbase");

            ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>() {

                public Void run() throws Exception {

                    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
                    conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://1.2.3.4:8020/user/hbase");
                    conf.set("hadoop.job.ugi", "hbase");

                    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

                    fs.createNewFile(new Path("/user/hbase/test"));

                    FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(new Path("/user/hbase"));
                    for(int i=0;i<status.length;i++){
                        System.out.println(status[i].getPath());
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Useful reference for those who have a similar problem:

- Cloudera blog post "[Authorization and Authentication In Hadoop](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/03/authorization-and-authentication-in-hadoop/)". Short, focused on simple explanation of hadoop security approaches. No information specific to Java API solution but good for basic understanding of the problem.

UPDATE:
Alternative for those who uses command line `hdfs` or `hadoop` utility without local user needed:

```
 HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs hdfs fs -put /root/MyHadoop/file1.txt /
```

What you actually do is you read local file in accordance to your local permissions but when placing file on HDFS you are authenticated like user `hdfs`.

This has pretty similar properties to API code illustrated:

1. You don't need `sudo`.
2. You don't need actually appropriate local user 'hdfs'.
3. You don't need to copy anything or change permissions because of previous points.

Comment: I've stumbled upon the same problem as yours. I'm trying to send Hadoop job from a remote client to the cluster that will execute it. In my case the problem is that **Cloudera's Hadoop 2.0.0 (Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.3.1) doesn't provide UserGroupInformation class** that you've used. It seems that corresponding Apache Hadoop versions doesn't provide it neither. There is just an enum named UserGroupInformation - [link](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/hadoop/api/org/apache/hadoop/security/UserGroupInformation.AuthenticationMethod.html). How could it be done in such a case then, in your opinion?

Comment: It's there, just it's not cloudera. I'm using 2.0.0-cdh4.3.1 hadoop client right now.

Comment: What do you mean by saying it's there? I've checked Apache Hadoop 2.0.6 API [[link](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.0.6-alpha/api/index.html)] as well as 2.1.0 API [[link](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.1.0-beta/api/index.html)] (those Javadocs that Apache provides on their website) and unfortunately there is no `UserGroupInformation` class, just the enum that doesn't help much. And by the way, isn't `2.0.0-cdh4.3.1` Hadoop that you've mentioned a Cloudera's Hadoop distribution?

Comment: Main point here is: CDH4 actually supports 0.20 client which is recommended. Just look here: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/01/an-update-on-apache-hadoop-1-0/ and then here: http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/HadoopTutorial/CDH4/Hadoop-Tutorial/ht_topic_5_2.html. As you can see they recommend to use 0.20 client.

Comment: Ok, I see. If I got it right, CDH4.3 supports both v0.20.2 (MapReduce) and v2.0.0 (MapReduce 2 - YARN) versions - [link](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products/cdh/projects-and-versions.html). The whole versioning thing is pretty obscure. But anyway, I still cannot find neither Hadoop API Javadoc nor hadoop-core JAR for CDH4.3 in Cloudera's repository [[link](https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-core/)] that has a `UserGroupInformation` class.

Comment: Honestly I always use 1.0.4 documentation and it looks good enough. For really though situations I just download CDH4 hadoop sources or javadoc. For example probably most needed things for you: http://maven.tempo-db.com/artifactory/list/cloudera/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-client/2.0.0-cdh4.3.1/ and http://maven.tempo-db.com/artifactory/list/cloudera/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-client/2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.1/

Comment: If you execute it like:

`java -jar myjar.jar`
File system will be LocalFileSystem.

To get DistributedFileSystem execute your jar like:

`hadoop jar myjar.jar`
or
`yarn jar myjar.jar`