# Accessing files in HDFS using Java

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to access a file in the HDFS using Java APIs, but everytime I am getting File Not Found. Code which I am using to access is :-

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.addResource(FileUtilConstants.ENV_HADOOP_HOME + FileUtilConstants.REL_PATH_CORE_SITE);
    conf.addResource(FileUtilConstants.ENV_HADOOP_HOME + FileUtilConstants.REL_PATH_HDFS_SITE);

    try {
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        Path hdfsfilePath = new Path(hdfsPath);
        logger.info("Filesystem URI : " + fs.getUri());
        logger.info("Filesystem Home Directory : " + fs.getHomeDirectory());
        logger.info("Filesystem Working Directory : " + fs.getWorkingDirectory());
        logger.info("HDFS File Path : " + hdfsfilePath);
        if (!fs.exists(hdfsfilePath)) {
            logger.error("File does not exists : " + hdfsPath);
        }
```

And here is the command line output from the code.

```
[root@koversevms ~]# java -jar /tmp/thetus-incendiary-koverse-extension-fileutils-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
13/07/10 02:47:18 INFO fileutils.HadoopFileChecksumUtils: Filesystem URI : file:///
13/07/10 02:47:18 INFO fileutils.HadoopFileChecksumUtils: Filesystem Home Directory : file:/root
13/07/10 02:47:18 INFO fileutils.HadoopFileChecksumUtils: Filesystem Working Directory : file:/root
13/07/10 02:47:18 INFO fileutils.HadoopFileChecksumUtils: HDFS File Path : /usr/hadoop/sample/sample.txt
13/07/10 02:47:18 ERROR fileutils.HadoopFileChecksumUtils: File does not exists : /usr/hadoop/sample/sample.txt
```

I am new to hadoop so I don't know what is going wrong.

Comment: Have you checked that there is such file in HDFS? If the file is on your local system than it doesn't mean it exists in HDFS. You can use web interface (usually http://YOUR_IP:50070/dfshealth.jsp) to check this.

Comment: Yes Yatul it exists in the HDFS.

    [root@koversevms ~]# hadoop fs -ls /usr/hadoop/sample/sample.txt
    Found 1 items
    -rw-r--r--   1 root supergroup      27848 2013-07-04 03:37 /usr/hadoop/sample/sample.txt

Comment: I resolved it. I modified the code to use path instead of String while adding xmls, it worked.

Earlier:-
    conf.addResource(FileUtilConstants.ENV_HADOOP_HOME + FileUtilConstants.REL_PATH_CORE_SITE);

Now
    conf.addResource(new Path(FileUtilConstants.ENV_HADOOP_HOME + FileUtilConstants.REL_PATH_CORE_SITE));

Answer (score 11):

Here is code fragment originally posted in context of answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941108/hdfs-access-from-remote-host-through-java-api-user-authentication). It should solve your question too despite intention of original question was different. Main point in your code is you have issues starting from scheme (`file://`). Please check `fs.defaultFS` variable in your configuration.

```
package org.myorg;

import java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;

public class HdfsTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            UserGroupInformation ugi
                = UserGroupInformation.createRemoteUser("hbase");

            ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>() {

                public Void run() throws Exception {

                    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
                    conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://1.2.3.4:8020/user/hbase");
                    conf.set("hadoop.job.ugi", "hbase");

                    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

                    fs.createNewFile(new Path("/user/hbase/test"));

                    FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(new Path("/user/hbase"));
                    for(int i=0;i<status.length;i++){
                        System.out.println(status[i].getPath());
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, may I ask you two question? Which version of hadoop HDFS do you use ? And where do you download the HDFS client java jar package ? I cannot find a valid hadoop HDFS client jar package for 2.7.1 hadoop HDFS.

Comment: What is wrong with this? http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client/2.7.1
Of course most of actual code comes with dependencies, not with hadoop-client-XXX.jar itself.