# Write Parquet format to HDFS using Java API with out using Avro and MR

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, parquet

What is the simple way to write **Parquet Format** to **HDFS** (using Java API) by **directly creating Parquet Schema** of a Pojo, without using **avro** and **MR**?

The samples I found were outdated and uses deprecated methods also uses one of Avro, spark or MR.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Effectively, there is not a lot of sample available for reading/writing Apache parquet files without the help of an external framework.

The core parquet library is parquet-column where you can find some test files reading/writing directly : https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-column/src/test/java/org/apache/parquet/io/TestColumnIO.java

You then just need to use the same functionality with an HDFS file. You can follow this SOW question for this : [Accessing files in HDFS using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564074/accessing-files-in-hdfs-using-java)

UPDATED : to respond to the deprecated parts of the API : AvroWriteSupport should be replaced by AvroParquetWriter and I check ParquetWriter it's not deprecated and can be used safely.

Regards,

Loïc

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think the provided link is a bit complex to understand, may be because I'm new to it.
So I went with avro schema, But again there are classes which are deprecated, 'AvroWriteSupport' and 'ParquetWriter'. What will be the alternatives for the above classes. 

sample code got from [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/how-to-convert-existing-data-into-parquet/)

Comment: You can use builder to build writer object instead of using constructor.