# Transform JSON into Parquet using EMR/Spark

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, avro, emr

I have a huge amount of `JSON` files that I need to transform into `Parquet`. They look something like this:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "props": {
    "prop1": "val1",
    "prop2": "val2"
  }
}
```

And I need to transform them into a `Parquet` file whose structure is this (nested properties are made top-level and get `_` as a suffix):

```
foo=bar
_prop1=val1
_prop2=val2
```

**Now here's the catch**: not all of the `JSON` documents have the same properties. So, if doc1 has `prop1` and `prop2`, but doc2 has `prop3`, the final `Parquet` file must have the three properties (some of them will be null for some of the records).

I understand that `Parquet` needs a `schema` up front, so my current plan is:

- Traverse all the `JSON` files
- Infer a `schema` per document (using Kite, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858856/json-object-to-parquet-format-using-java-without-converting-to-avrowithout-usin))
- Merge all the `schemas`
- Start writing the `Parquet`

This approach strikes me as very complicated, slow and error-prone. I'm wondering if there's a better way to achieve this using `Spark`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Spark already does this for you. When it reads JSON documents and you do not specify a schema it will infer/merge them for you. So in my case, something like this would work:

```
val flattenedJson: RDD[String] = sparkContext.hadoopFile("/file")
  .map(/*parse/flatten json*/)

sqlContext
  .read
  .json(flattenedJson)
  .write
  .parquet("destination")
```