# How to read from amazon EMR HDFS remotley (or any other hadoop distance server)

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, hdfs

I'm well aware how to use

`hadoop fs -get .....` in unix

How would you get a file from amazon aws (HDFS) using java ?

This is a distance server.

But i need to supply somehow a (ppk file).

How can it be done in java ?

addition to the code from this  [link](https://sites.google.com/site/hadoopandhive/home/hadoop-how-to-read-a-file-from-hdfs) .

Comment: Edited the grammar and code markup

Comment: Are you looking to get a file into HDFS from amazon aws ?

Comment: I need to get files from hdfs in java. Without ftp get.

Comment: you need to use hadoop file system API (`org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem`.
Look into `copyToLocalFile` method described   here https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#copyToLocalFile(boolean,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)

Comment: i cant use unix command - i am working from a distant server - and need to use java only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding upon what 'sras' has already noted.  You have to use org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem API.  That API can be remotely invoked so that you can  to connect to HDFS from a remote host.

The following stackoverflow question actually has a code snippet and explanation on authenticating your request in some detail.

[HDFS access from remote host through Java API, user authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941108/hdfs-access-from-remote-host-through-java-api-user-authentication)

(You wont be connecting to the server over SSH using a PPK file - but over HTTP to HDFS daemon)