# Create directory on remote hdfs from localhost using java

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, namenode

Create a directory on the remote HDFS from localhost

Written code but don't understand what and where to write the `core-site.xml` and the `hdfs-site.xml`.

```
public class HadoopCall {

    public void demomkdir(String dir) throws IOException
    {
        Configuration obj = new Configuration();

        obj.set("fs.defaultFS", "http://datlpdsnn01.pds.in.****.com:50070/");
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(obj);

        Path pth = new Path(dir);
        fs.mkdirs(pth);
        System.out.println("created");
        fs.close(); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HadoopCall oj = new HadoopCall();
        oj.demomkdir("user/*******/javacodemkdir");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference : [Hadoop Configuration class](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html)

As given in the above link:

> core-default.xml: Read-only defaults for hadoop.
>
> core-site.xml: Site-specific configuration for a given hadoop
>   installation.

Both are files, with configuration specific to the installation and the default ones. You can add the path of any of the above xml with the method [addResource(Path path)](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html#addResource(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)). If the paths are not given, the xml file paths are inferred from classpath variables.

Comment: actually my project is in Eclipse which is in my local machine. I want to know whether I have to create manually core-site.xml, etc. or it will take automatically from the server! Please be in touch because I am not finding anyone with the answer

Comment: also could you please tell what are the dependencies I should include in build.gradle  I have Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.14.2. Also Eclipse Oxygen, Java is 1.8 on the local machine. Hadoop is one some another server. I have two active namenodes. I can use ssh command to login the hdfs. But I am not the admin

Comment: You can use this link to get started:
https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/java/how-to-read-hdfs-file-in-java.html

Comment: My hdfs is not in my local computer. It is on remote server. Do I have to enter the password. Because it is in the remote server I don't know where the core-site.xml is?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941108/hdfs-access-from-remote-host-through-java-api-user-authentication

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it worked. Thank you very much! Keep helping. Thanks